# react native Table GridView

Tags: react-native

how to build table gridview in react native like in picture or in code snippet

[image]

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ListView` component, the first row would be your header (`renderHeader`), others are rows (`renderRow`).

Both row and header would be the same component containing a parent `View` with `flexDirection: 'row'` with 4 `Text` components. Each Text component would have a `flex: 1` if you want them to be of the same widths.

Comment: This should be accepted answer, `flex: 1` did the trick for me. Thank you!

Comment: `ListView` has been deprecated: [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) and [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) are the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import { registerComponent } from "react-native-playground";
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 50,
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    flex: 1,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    padding: 2,
                    justifyContent: "space-around"
                }}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>Jill</Text>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>Smith</Text>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>50</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 50,
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    flex: 1,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    padding: 2,
                    justifyContent: "space-around"
                }}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>Eve</Text>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>Jackson</Text>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>94</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 50,
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    flex: 1,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    padding: 2,
                    justifyContent: "space-around"
                }}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>First Name</Text>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>Last Name</Text>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>Age</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
}
registerComponent(App);
```

Here's the working code https://rnplay.org/apps/e3MZAw

Comment: how to combine with ListView? i need ListView for get datasource from rest api